# Decode the String having same key

Tags: php, json

```
{"": "attachment-2","": "attachment-1"}
```

I am getting this JSON-encoded string (or an oher format... let me know) from parsing a mail and I can not change it. How can I decode it?

Comment: `json_decode` in PHP see : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do...  What is your problem?

Comment: As far as I can see this JSON is invalid anyway.

Comment: Note though that this is not a properly formatted json string.  Proper JSON cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: Did you guys even *try* the code you suggest @mogria and baba? You only get one element since duplicate keys are not supported. - and according to jsonlint it's not syntactically invalid. it just silently overwrites the first element with the same key

Comment: Screen shot of what I am getting after parsing the mail ! i want to decode content-id-map

http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/685/5568730832.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This JSON response is invalid as @ThiefMaster mentioned, because JSON doesn't support `duplicated keys`.

You should contact the service you're trying to request this response from.

In case you have a valid JSON response you can decode it using the `json_decode` function
which returns an `object` or an `array` (depends on the second parameter);

For example: (Object)

```
$json_string = '{"keyOne": "attachment-2","keyTwo": "attachment-1"}';
$decoded = json_decode($json_string);

print $obj->keyOne; //attachment-2
print $obj->keyTwo; //attachment-1
```

Another option is to write your own decoder function.

Comment: contacted the service. fixed the issue.from their side only.

Comment: JSON does allow duplicate keys.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object

Comment: @dvijaz You're right, I might didn't rephrase it correctly.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use a JSON parser for this as it will always overwrite the first element due to the same keys. The only *proper* solution would be asking whoever creates that "JSON" to fix his code to either use an array or an object with unique keys.

If that's not an option the only thing you can do it rewriting the JSON to have unique keys before parsing it using `json_decode()`

Assuming it always gives you proper JSON and the duplicate keys are always empty you can replace `"":` with `"random-string":` - `preg_replace_callback()` is your friend in this case:

```
$lame = '{"": "attachment-2","": "attachment-1"}';
$json = preg_replace_callback('/"":/', function($m) {
    return '"' . uniqid() . '":';
}, $lame);
var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

Output:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["5076bdf9c2567"]=>
  string(12) "attachment-2"
  ["5076bdf9c25b5"]=>
  string(12) "attachment-1"
}
```

Comment: Screen shot of what I am getting after parsing the mail ! i want to decode content-id-map easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/685/5568730832.png

Comment: this looks right way, i can go .

Can u help me to built a function to so that after result ...I get the same key as its value.

Answer (score 0):

Decode it yourself?

```
$myStr = '{"": "attachment-2","": "attachment-1"}';
$vars = explode(',',$myStr);
$arr = array();
foreach($vars as $v){
    list($key,$value) = explode(':',$v);
    $key = substr($key,strpos($key,'"'),strpos($key,'"')-strrpos($key,'"'));
    $value = substr($value,strpos($value,'"'),strpos($value,'"')-strrpos($value,'"'));
    if($key=='')$arr[] = $value;
    else $arr[$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: This looks a valid , but lengthy code. :|
Thanx by the way. ! a function can help me to replace a key with its value

Comment: You cannot do this. `:` may be contained inside a string.

Comment: ah you're right! Didn't think about that... Well, to use with caution then ^.^

Comment: It also lacks support for any escape sequences, non-string datatypes etc.