# I would like to pass the same ajax property

Tags: mysql, sql, ajax, properties, mybatis

mybatis

> select id="selectPlur" parameterType="map" resultMap="elementResultMap" 
>       ${sql} 
>     /select

mysql

> select * from (select * from ELEMENT where I_NO=1) T1 
>    inner join (select * from ELEMENT where I_NO=3) T2 using (G_NO) 
>    inner join ( select * from ELEMENT where I_NO=5) T3 using (G_NO)

mysql data result

> G_NO | I_NO | I_REQ | I_NO | I_REQ | I_NO | I_REQ |
>       1     |    1    |    10     |    3     |    20     |    5   |    1      |
>       4     |    1    |    100   |    3     |    10     |    5   |    1      |

ajax result

> [0]"gNo": 1 
>        "iNo": 1 
>        "iReq": 10 
>   [1]"gNo": 4 
>        "iNo": 1  
>        "iReq": 100

ajax result what I want

> [0]"gNo": 1 
>        "iNo": 1 
>        "iReq": 10 
>        "iNo": 3
>        "iReq": 20 
>        "iNo": 5 
>        "iReq": 1 
>   [1]"gNo": 4 
>        "iNo": 1  
>        "iReq": 100 
>        "iNo": 3
>        "iReq": 10 
>        "iNo": 5 
>        "iReq": 1

in mySQL, I execute ‘mysql’ statement and it returns what I want like ‘mysql data result’.
but I`m using mybatis with eclipse 
because of property name, result has only one “iNo” and “iReq” like ‘ajax result’ 
How can I get result like ‘ajax result what I want”?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly because most JSON implementations [do not support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object) duplicate keys.

You might need to change the structure of the data you return to client for example rename the columns like this:

```
select G_NO, T1.I_NO AS T1_I_NO, T1.I_REQ AS T1_I_REQ,
       T2.I_NO AS T2_I_NO, T2.I_REQ AS T2_I_REQ,
       T3.I_NO AS T3_I_NO, T3.I_REQ AS T3_I_REQ
  from (select * from ELEMENT where I_NO=1) T1 
  inner join (select * from ELEMENT where I_NO=3) T2 using (G_NO) 
  inner join ( select * from ELEMENT where I_NO=5) T3 using (G_NO)
```

In this case the result would be

```
[0]"gNo": 1 
   "t1INo": 1 
   "t1IReq": 10 
   "t2INo": 3
   "t2IReq": 20 
   "t3INo": 5 
   "t3IReq": 1 
[1]"gNo": 4 
   "t1INo": 1 
   "t1IReq": 100 
   "t2INo": 3
   "t2IReq": 10 
   "t3INo": 5 
   "t3IReq": 1
```

Comment: Became very helpful, tank you.