# Need Example of passing Jasper Reports Parameters for REST v2 API using JSON

Tags: python, json, rest, parameters, jasperserver

When I look at the documentation for passing parameters to the Jasper Report REST 2 API here: http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide/v550/running-report-asynchronously I see that I need to have a "parameters" dict.  The example in the link shows the XML which is not all that useful since it's unclear exactly what the equivalent JSON should look like.  The closest I could find is in this link: http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide/v56/modifying-report-parameters.  Now, I am sending the equivalent of that to the server (and every other permutation I can think of), and I continue to get a "400 Client Error: Bad Request" back.  I could really use an *exact* example of the python code to generate the required "parameters" parameter for say "my_parameter_1="test_value_1".

Here is my current POST data (with a few params missing for brevity).  I know this is correct since the report works fine if I omit the "parameters" parameter:

```
    {
      'outputFormat': 'pdf', 
      'parameters': [{'name': 'ReportID', 'value': ['my_value_1']}], 
      'async': 'true', 
      'pages': '', 
      'interactive': 'false'
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, thanks to rafkacz1 @ http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/825719/json-equivalent-xml-post-reportexecutions-rest-service who posted an answer, I figured it out.  As he report there, the required format is:

```
    "parameters":{
         "reportParameter":[
             {"name":"my_parameter_1","value":["my_value_1"]}
          ]
     }
```

Pay particular attention to the plurality of "**reportParameter**".

Answer (score 6):

Nice Job there Staggart. I got it now. Because I wasn't reading with max. scrutinity, I wasted some additional time. So the interested coder is not only advised to be aware of the nested, syntactictally interesting reportParameter-property, but especially that the value-property inside that is an array. I suppose one could pass some form of Lists/Arrays/Collections here?

What irritated me was, if I should construct more than one "reportParameter" property, but that would be nonsense according to 
[Does JSON syntax allow duplicate keys in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object).

So just for the record, how to post multiple parameters:

```
{
    "reportUnitUri": "/reports/Top10/Top10Customers",
    "async": true,
    "freshData": true,
    "saveDataSnapshot": false,
    "outputFormat": "pdf",
    "interactive": false,
    "ignorePagination": true,
    "parameters": {
        "reportParameter": [
            {
                "name": "DATE_START_STRING",
                "value": ["14.07.2014"]
            },
            {
                "name": "DATE_END_STRING",
                "value": ["14.10.2014"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If someone accidently is struggling with communicating with jasper via REST and PHP. Do yourself a favour and use the [Requests for PHP](https://github.com/rmccue/Requests) instead of pure CURL. It even has a fallback for internally using Sockets instead of CURL, when latter isn't available.

Upvote for you Staggart.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that worked for me. Im using Python 2.7, and the community edition of Jaspersoft. Like the C# example above, this example also uses the rest v2 which made it very simple for me to download a pdf report quickly

```
import requests

sess = requests.Session()   
auth = ('username', 'password')
res = sess.get(url='http://your.jasper.domain:8080/jasperserver/', auth=auth)
res.raise_for_status()
url = 'http://your.jasper.domain:8080/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/report_folder/sub_folder/report_name.pdf'
params = {'Month':'2', 'Year':'2017','Project': 'ProjectName'}
res = sess.get(url=url, params=params, stream=True)
res.raise_for_status()
path = '/path/to/Downloads/report_name.pdf'
with open(path, "wb") as f:
    f.write(res.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full example about generate a report using Rest V2, in my case it's running on C#:

```
try {
    var server = "http://localhost:8080/jasperserver";
    var login = server + "/rest/login";
    var report = "/rest_v2/reports/organization/Reports/report_name.pdf";
    var client = new WebClient();

    //Set the content type of the request
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    //Set the username and password
    NameValueCollection parametros = new NameValueCollection();
    parametros.Add("j_username", "jasperadmin");
    parametros.Add("j_password", "123456");

    //Request to login
    client.UploadValues(login, "POST", parametros);

    //Get session cookie
    string session = client.ResponseHeaders.Get("Set-Cookie");

    //Set session cookie to the next request
    client.Headers.Add("Cookie", session);

    //Generate report with parameters: "start" and "end"
    var reporte = client.DownloadData(server + report + "?start=2015-10-01&end=2015-10-10");

    //Returns the report as response
    return File(reporte, "application/pdf", "test.pdf");
}catch(WebException e){
    //return Content("There was a problem, status code: " + ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode);
    return null;
}
```