# Writing JSON schema to detect objects with duplicate names

Tags: json, jsonschema

According to the following post;

[Does JSON syntax allow duplicate keys in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object?lq=1)

Keys with the same name in JSON are valid, but most parsers will override the value with the last value it finds. Is there anyway in a json schema to detect duplicate names and throw an error? I want all json keys to have unique names in an object.

Comment: It would require a custom parser which is duplicate-aware to parse the schema itself. I don't think it exists yet.

Comment: Ahh thats a shame, i figured this must have been an issue for other people, is there really no solution already out there?

Comment: A relatively fast search on Google gave no results. I guess your best bet would write your own JSON parser which accounts for such duplicate keys. Interstellarly far from a optimal solution, but better than nothing. You could also preprocess your JSON to something non-duplicated.

Comment: Ye i tried searching for a while with no luck, ok no problem, ye i'm already in a pre-process work flow so adding some task to remove duplicate objects from json should be relatively easy. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Json-schema works with valid JSON objects, so there is nothing it can do to prevent duplicate keys.

I would suggest you to use a jsonlint as a preprocess before validating with json-schema validator. It will depend on your programming language but here you have some choices:

- [javascript](https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint).
- [PHP](https://github.com/Seldaek/jsonlint)
- [Python](https://github.com/dmeranda/demjson)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a method to detect the duplicate keys in C#, then just use JObject.Parse method with specific parameter in Json.NET.

```
try
{
    var _= JObject.Parse(jsonString, new JsonLoadSettings
    {
        DuplicatePropertyNameHandling = DuplicatePropertyNameHandling.Error
    });
}
catch(JsonReaderException ex)
{
    return BadRequest($"Invalid json file, {ex.Message}.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the accepted answer states, JSON Schema just cannot enforce the check you want to implement (the equivalent of `minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"` in XML).

I just would like to add that the link to the Python validator is broken.  Python programmers might install [demjson3](https://pypi.org/project/demjson3/) and run `jsonlint my-json-file.json`; duplicate elements will trigger a warning (`Warning: Object contains duplicate key`)