# How to solve the closure issue in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, closures

I have a sample todo app in angularjs. My list of todos is an array. but everytime only the last value of array item is getting added to li's.

I have replicated the issue on a jsbin.

http://jsbin.com/simafuzidi/3/edit

I want the list of todo item to have all the fields that are typed in text boxes and not just the last one. I know this is a closure problem but I am not sure how to solve this in the current circumstances.

thanks

```
$scope.addTodo = function() {
  $scope.todos.push({text:$scope.todoText1,text:$scope.todoText2,text:$scope.todoText3,text:$scope.todoText4,done:false});
  $scope.todoText1 = '';
  $scope.todoText2 = '';
  $scope.todoText3 = '';
  $scope.todoText4 = '';
};




<form ng-submit="addTodo()">
        <input type="text" ng-model="todoText1"  size="30"
               placeholder="add new todo here1"><br />
        <input type="text" ng-model="todoText2"  size="30"
               placeholder="add new todo here2"><br />
        <input type="text" ng-model="todoText3"  size="30"
               placeholder="add new todo here3"><br />
         <input type="text" ng-model="todoText4"  size="30"
               placeholder="add new todo here4"><br />
         <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
      </form>
```

Comment: @Satpal: I put  a part of code, but you would be better off seeing the live problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should have seen console error in [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/simafuzidi/3/edit) and go through [Does JSON syntax allow duplicate keys in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object)

> Line 8: Duplicate key 'text'.

*Code*

```
$scope.todos = [
  {todoText1:'learn angular', 
   done:true
  },
  {
    todoText1:'build an angular app', done:false
  }];
$scope.addTodo = function() {
  $scope.todos.push(
    {
      todoText1:$scope.todoText1,
      todoText2:$scope.todoText2,
      todoText3:$scope.todoText3,
      todoText4:$scope.todoText4,
     done:false
    });
  $scope.todoText1 = '';
  $scope.todoText2 = '';
  $scope.todoText3 = '';
  $scope.todoText4 = '';
};
```

*HTML*

```
  <ul class="unstyled">
    <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
      <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.todoText1}} {{todo.todoText2}} {{todo.todoText3}} {{todo.todoText4}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/joliza/2/)

Comment: Thanks, but it is not just how to fix, question  is where does closure come into play here.

Comment: Don't suggest string concatenation as alternative to a object with multiple keys -.-

Comment: No, it's not. It's a hacky / useless way to remove duplicate keys. I'm sure you can think of a better alternative than string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your push statement should look something like this.

```
  $scope.todos.push({text:$scope.todoText1,done:false},{text:$scope.todoText2,done:false},{text:$scope.todoText3,done:false},{text:$scope.todoText4,done:false});
```

If you want to push all items.

Comment: That will create 4 todos, I just want todo one item and moreover I wanted to understand how can closures solve this problem in angularjs

Comment: @Cerbrus: are you telling me this isn't a closure problem
http://jsbin.com/simafuzidi/3/edit