# Meteor MongoDB Corruption Single Document with Duplicate Fields

Tags: json, mongodb, meteor

I have a very strange situation with a couple of meteor applications that I am running on a semi-production machine.

Basically, I have a few documents (I'm actually not sure how many at the moment) that have duplicate fields:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5006040239bcf91fab6311e5"),
        "first_name" : "First Name",
        "landline" : "555 555-5555",
        "last_name" : "Last Name",
        "prior_email" : "newrandomemail@example.net",
        "prior_email" : "newrandomemail@example.net",
}
```

The mongo docs are a little vague about the validity of this state:

> BSON documents may have more than one field with the same name. Most
>   MongoDB interfaces, however, represent MongoDB with a structure (e.g.
>   a hash table) that does not support duplicate field names. If you need
>   to manipulate documents that have more than one field with the same
>   name, see the driver documentation for your driver.
>
> Some documents created by internal MongoDB processes may have
>   duplicate fields, but no MongoDB process will ever add duplicate
>   fields to an existing user document.
>   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#field-names

I guess there's some argument as to whether or not JSON should ever have duplicate keys: [Does JSON syntax allow duplicate keys in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object)
but I can't imagine that a javascript (NodeJS, Meteor, etc) driver would ever intentionally do that.

It's a little complicated, though, because we have two Meteor applications sharing a single database. They're basically the front and admin ends of our software. In order to run both of the applications, I start one first with:

```
meteor -p 3000
```

Then I start the second with:

```
export MONGO_URL="mongodb://localhost:3001/meteor"
meteor -p 3002
```

The strangest thing is that when using the second application, the Meteor findOne() call for that document shows "oldrandomemail@example.net" for the "prior_email" value - the value that had been set previously and then later changed to "newrandomemail@example.net".

I know that these aren't exactly best practices for production deployment, but I'm wondering if anyone else has seen this or has any idea what might be triggering it...

EDIT: 
The code that updates the database is pretty basic:

```
Subscribers.update(this._id, {$set: {'prior_email': 'newrandomemail@example.net'}});
```

Comment: While technically duplicate keys are allowed in BSON, I would not expect a JSON document or JavaScript object to have duplicate keys. The observed behaviour is usually that the last value listed for a duplicate key ends up being the value in the JSON document (and some folks even (ab)use this as a [hack to add comments to JSON](http://fadefade.com/json-comments.html)). I also don't think your issue is related to using a single MongoDB deployment for multiple application instances. Can you share a code snippet showing how `prior_email` is being set?

Comment: Also, by chance are you editing any data with a third party admin tool (i.e. outside of your Meteor code)? It's more likely for duplicate fields to accidentally be created using a lower-level driver like C or C++; higher level languages tend to use a dictionary or hash representation of the MongoDB document that won't allow for duplicate keys without extra effort ;-).

Comment: No I'm not using any third party admin tool, just Meteor and the mongo console...

Comment: So what exactly is the question here? How to fix the documents? How did this happen?

Comment: Honestly, either would be amazing. Really any insight into wth is going on here...

Answer (score -1):

If you are certain that the prior_email identifies duplicate records, you can ensure a unique index with the dropDups:true index creation option:

```
 db.collection.ensureIndex({'prior_email' : 1}, {unique : true, dropDups : true})
```

This will keep the first unique document for each prior_email value, and drop any subsequent documents that would otherwise cause a duplicate key violation.

**Important Note**: Any documents missing the prior_email field will be considered as having a null value, so subsequent documents missing the key field will be deleted. You can add the **sparse:true** index creation option so the index only applies to documents with a prior_email field.

**Obvious caution**: Take a backup of your database, and try this in a staging environment first if you are concerned about unintended data loss.

**references**: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-sparse-index/
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't actually want prior_email to be a unique index. It would be fine for two separate documents to have the same prior_email field, but I don't want one single document to have two prior_email fields.