# How to convert an array to JSON format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sapui5, keyvaluepair

I have a string array, e.g.

```
p[]={"John","Kevin","Lex"}
```

I want to convert it to JSON so that the data appears in key-value pair like:

```
{
    "name":"John",       
    "name":"Kevin"
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What language are you using ?

Comment: It's not recommended to use a duplicated key in a JSON. You are repeating the key "name"

Comment: I am using JavaScript in sapui5

Comment: @RakehSahu: Do you still need help with this? Are you sure that the JS object you printed is your desired output? As AmauryMedeiros pointed out, you're duplicating the `name` key, which you really should avoid (if it's even allowed at all).

Comment: Your second snippet is missing the name `"Lex"`.  Is this a typo?

Comment: It is really not clear what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

First, `p[]={...}` is not legal JavaScript.  I'll assume you meant this:

```
p = ["John","Kevin","Lex"]
```

Second, duplicate keys in JSON is allowed by the spec, but it is not supported by most JSON libraries.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object).

This is because most languages (like the JavaScript you're using) serialize associative array structures to JSON objects.  Associative arrays explicitly map keys to values uniquely:

```
> a = {}
> a.name = "John"
    {name: "John"}
> a.name = "Jeff"
    {name: "Jeff"}
```

So if you try the simplest possible JSON stringification mechanism on `p` or `a`, you don't get what you want:

```
> JSON.stringify(p)
    '["John","Kevin","Lex"]'
> JSON.stringify(a)
    '{"name":"Jeff"}'
```

Try this function:

```
var many_named_JSON = function(array_of_names) {
  array_string =  JSON.stringify(array_of_names.map(function (item) {
    return "name:" + item;
  }));
  contents_regex = /\[(.*)\]/g;
  return ("{" + contents_regex.exec(array_string)[1] + "}").replace(/name:/g, 'name":"');
};
```

Here it is working:

```
> many_named_JSON(["John","Kevin","Lex"])
    '{"name":"john","name":"jeff"}'
```

Answer (score -1):

You wanted something like [this](http://jsbin.com/zoqaziqoye/edit?html,output)?

```
var aArray = ["John","Kevin","Lex"];
var oMainObject = {};
var aMainObjectArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < aArray.length; i++){
var oObject = {};
oObject.name = aArray[i];
aMainObjectArray.push(oObject);
)  
oMainObject.data = aMainObjectArray;
```

As a result, `oMainObject` object contains:

```
{data: [{"name":"John"},{"name":"Kevin"},{"name":"Lex"}]}
```

Comment: Probably not, seeing as your output and his output are completely different.

Comment: If I understand correctly, he wants to use the json object as a source for a json model. Else, there is a little sense in the object he showed in his question. Of course, I may be wrong.

Comment: He wants `'{ "name":"John", "name":"Kevin" }'`.  You gave `'[{"name":"John"},{"name":"Kevin"},{"name":"Lex"}]'`.

Comment: Please include your code in your answer, and not just a link to it. Thanks!