# Merging Concatenating JSON(B) columns in query

Tags: postgresql

Using Postgres 9.4, I am looking for a way to merge two (or more) `json` or `jsonb` columns in a query. Consider the following table as an example:

```
  id | json1        | json2
----------------------------------------
  1   | {'a':'b'}   | {'c':'d'}
  2   | {'a1':'b2'} | {'f':{'g' : 'h'}}
```

Is it possible to have the query return the following:

```
  id | json
----------------------------------------
  1   | {'a':'b', 'c':'d'}
  2   | {'a1':'b2', 'f':{'g' : 'h'}}
```

Unfortunately, I can't define a function as described [here](http://blog.endpoint.com/2013/07/merging-jsons-in-postgresql.html). Is this possible with a "traditional" query?

Comment: Which version of postgres are you using ?

Comment: @ClémentPrévost I use postgres 9.4

Comment: What do you want to happen if `json1` has a key/value pair ALSO in `json2`? Right-precedent, or merge?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Here is the complete list of build-in functions that can be used to create json objects in PostgreSQL. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html

- `row_to_json` and `json_object` doest not allow you to define your own keys, so it can't be used here
- `json_build_object` expect you to know by advance how many keys and values our object will have, that's the case in your example, but should not be the case in the real world
- `json_object` looks like a good tool to tackle this problem but it forces us to cast our values to text so we can't use this one either

Well... ok, wo we can't use any classic functions.

Let's take a look at some aggregate functions and hope for the best... http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html

`json_object_agg` Is the only aggregate function that build objects, that's our only chance to tackle this problem. The trick here is to find the correct way to feed the `json_object_agg` function.

Here is my test table and data

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  json1 JSONB,
  json2 JSONB
);

INSERT INTO test (json1, json2) VALUES
  ('{"a":"b", "c":"d"}', '{"e":"f"}'),
  ('{"a1":"b2"}', '{"f":{"g" : "h"}}');
```

And after some trials and errors with `json_object` here is a query you can use to merge json1 and json2 in PostgreSQL 9.4

```
WITH all_json_key_value AS (
  SELECT id, t1.key, t1.value FROM test, jsonb_each(json1) as t1
  UNION
  SELECT id, t1.key, t1.value FROM test, jsonb_each(json2) as t1
)
SELECT id, json_object_agg(key, value) 
FROM all_json_key_value 
GROUP BY id
```

For PostgreSQL 9.5+, look at [Zubin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44038002).

Answer (score 157):

In Postgres 9.5+ you can merge JSONB like this:

```
select json1 || json2;
```

Or, if it's JSON, coerce to JSONB if necessary:

```
select json1::jsonb || json2::jsonb;
```

Or:

```
select COALESCE(json1::jsonb||json2::jsonb, json1::jsonb, json2::jsonb);
```

(Otherwise, any null value in `json1` or `json2` returns an empty row)

For example:

```
select data || '{"foo":"bar"}'::jsonb from photos limit 1;
                               ?column?
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"foo": "bar", "preview_url": "https://unsplash.it/500/720/123"}
```

Kudos to @MattZukowski for pointing this out in a comment.

Comment: This doesn't actually deep merge.. `SELECT '{"a":[1,2,3]}'::jsonb || '{"a":[4,5,6]}'::jsonb;` Key/V pairs in the rhs clobber the LHS.

Comment: @EvanCarroll JSONB not allow duplicated key. So, it cannot do the deep merge.

Comment: @JianHe Sure it can, and it'll clobber. Which is allowable in the spec. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23195243/124486 Try it `select '{"foo":42}'::jsonb || '{"foo":20}'::jsonb;`

Comment: @EvanCarroll. Now I am at 13.2, Windows version.  select '{"foo":42}'::jsonb || '{"foo":20}'::jsonb; returns ` {"foo": 20} ` I thought you want  `{"foo": [20,42]}`

Comment: No, that's a recursive merge. It doesn't do that. ;) But you can do that manually for one level by merging the arrays, if you know the fields you want to merge beforehand.

Comment: `select json1 || json2;` returns null if any of them is null. Same with `coalesce(json1||json2)`. `coalesce(json1, json2)` returns only json1.

Comment: If you have nulls, using an empty '{}'::jsonb` object would allow you to merge them correctly.

Answer (score 19):

Looks like nobody proposed this kind of solution yet, so here's my take, using [custom aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createaggregate.html):

```
create or replace aggregate jsonb_merge_agg(jsonb)
(
    sfunc = jsonb_concat,
    stype = jsonb,
    initcond = '{}'
);

create or replace function jsonb_concat(a jsonb, b jsonb) returns jsonb
    as 'select $1 || $2'
    language sql
    immutable
    parallel safe
;
```

> Note: this is using `||` which replaces existing values at same path instead of deeply merging them.

Now `jsonb_merge_agg` is accessible like so:

```
select jsonb_merge_agg(some_col) from some_table group by something;
```

Comment: This is the way!

Comment: How do you ensure that it follows merging order? such as id 3 would be written only after id 2 was written on id 1

Comment: great question for which I don't have an answer. I just know there exists the syntax `some_agg(x order by x desc)`, as seen here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-aggregate.html#AEN15846

Comment: or maybe simply the regular order by would be enough

Answer (score 10):

This function would merge nested json objects

```
create or replace function jsonb_merge(CurrentData jsonb,newData jsonb)
 returns jsonb
 language sql
 immutable
as $jsonb_merge_func$
 select case jsonb_typeof(CurrentData)
   when 'object' then case jsonb_typeof(newData)
     when 'object' then (
       select    jsonb_object_agg(k, case
                   when e2.v is null then e1.v
                   when e1.v is null then e2.v
                   when e1.v = e2.v then e1.v 
                   else jsonb_merge(e1.v, e2.v)
                 end)
       from      jsonb_each(CurrentData) e1(k, v)
       full join jsonb_each(newData) e2(k, v) using (k)
     )
     else newData
   end
   when 'array' then CurrentData || newData
   else newData
 end
$jsonb_merge_func$;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Here my 2 cents: I've modifyed slightly, to allow only unique values in nested arrays, just replace `CurrentData || newData` in array part with `array_to_json(array(select distinct jsonb_array_elements( CurrentData || newData)))::jsonb`.  **TODO:** not use JSON as intermdiate instead of JOSNB, find correct function for arrays

Answer (score 9):

Also you can tranform json into text, concatenate, replace and convert back to json. Using the same data from Clément you can do:

```
SELECT replace(
    (json1::text || json2::text), 
    '}{', 
    ', ')::json 
FROM test
```

You could also concatenate all json1 into single json with:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(
    array_agg((json1))::text,
    '}"(,)"{|\\| |^{"|"}$', 
    '\1', 
    'g'
)::json
FROM test
```

This is a very old solution, since 9.4 you should use `json_object_agg` and simple `||` concatenate operator. Keeping here just for reference.

Comment: In Postgres 9.5, assuming your columns as JSONB, you can just do `SELECT json1 || json2` to merge the JSON values.

Comment: This approach can result in duplicative keys, e.g. `{"a":1} + {"a":2} = {"a":1, "a":2}`

Comment: I don't see that: select '{"a":1}'::jsonb || '{"a":2}'::jsonb = {"a": 2}

Comment: this approach allow keep the order of items in json, in other cases concatination jsonb looks very nice

Comment: I'm using an older version of postgres and `replace(old_value::text, '}', ', "new_key": "new_value"}')::jsonb` was the only thing that worked. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

However this question is answered already some time ago; the fact that when `json1` and `json2` contain the same key; the key appears twice in the document, does not seem to be [best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object).

Therefore u can use this `jsonb_merge` function with PostgreSQL 9.5:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_merge(jsonb1 JSONB, jsonb2 JSONB)
    RETURNS JSONB AS $$
    DECLARE
      result JSONB;
      v RECORD;
    BEGIN
       result = (
    SELECT json_object_agg(KEY,value)
    FROM
      (SELECT jsonb_object_keys(jsonb1) AS KEY,
              1::int AS jsb,
              jsonb1 -> jsonb_object_keys(jsonb1) AS value
       UNION SELECT jsonb_object_keys(jsonb2) AS KEY,
                    2::int AS jsb,
                    jsonb2 -> jsonb_object_keys(jsonb2) AS value ) AS t1
           );
       RETURN result;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The following query returns the concatenated jsonb columns, where the keys in `json2` are dominant over the keys in `json1`:

```
select id, jsonb_merge(json1, json2) from test
```

Comment: Doesn't  work for PostgreSQL 9.4.4:   SELECT jsonb_merge('{"11111":1, "2":2}'::jsonb, '{"11111":3}'::jsonb)

Comment: Tested on 9.5 - works well. To add priorities just replace UNION with UNION ALL in function.

Comment: @Dmitry it doesn't work at all. `select jsonb_merge('{"a":{"nested":1}}'::jsonb, '{"a":{"also nested":2}}'::jsonb);` should result in `a` with 2 properties, it doesn't.

Comment: @Phill; you are correct but u can solve this by adding a sublayer of jsonb_object_keys grouped by the keys with another aggregate function -- if the subvalue is a jsonb object. This can be repeated until you merge the subsubsublayer...etc

Comment: @API i created a new version with a JavaScript merge function: https://gist.github.com/phillip-haydon/54871b746201793990a18717af8d70dc I haven't tidied it up yet tho. Works on samples docs I have at work.

Answer (score 6):

FYI, if someone's using jsonb in >= 9.5 and they only care about top-level elements being merged without duplicate keys, then it's as easy as using the || operator:

```
select '{"a1": "b2"}'::jsonb || '{"f":{"g" : "h"}}'::jsonb;
      ?column?           
-----------------------------
 {"a1": "b2", "f": {"g": "h"}}
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this, if anyone having an issue for merging two JSON object

```
select table.attributes::jsonb || json_build_object('foo',1,'bar',2)::jsonb FROM table where table.x='y';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_merge(pCurrentData jsonb, pMergeData jsonb, pExcludeKeys text[])
RETURNS jsonb IMMUTABLE LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
    SELECT json_object_agg(key,value)::jsonb
    FROM (
        WITH to_merge AS (
            SELECT * FROM jsonb_each(pMergeData) 
        )
        SELECT *
        FROM jsonb_each(pCurrentData)
        WHERE key NOT IN (SELECT key FROM to_merge)
     AND ( pExcludeKeys ISNULL OR key <> ALL(pExcludeKeys))
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM to_merge
    ) t;
$$;
```

SELECT jsonb_merge('{"a": 1, "b": 9, "c": 3, "e":5}'::jsonb, '{"b": 2, "d": 4}'::jsonb, '{"c","e"}'::text[]) as jsonb

Answer (score 2):

works well as an alternative to || when recursive deep merge is required (found [here](http://blog.bguiz.com/2017/json-merge-postgresql/)) :

```
create or replace function jsonb_merge_recurse(orig jsonb, delta jsonb)
returns jsonb language sql as $$
    select
        jsonb_object_agg(
            coalesce(keyOrig, keyDelta),
            case
                when valOrig isnull then valDelta
                when valDelta isnull then valOrig
                when (jsonb_typeof(valOrig) <> 'object' or jsonb_typeof(valDelta) <> 'object') then valDelta
                else jsonb_merge_recurse(valOrig, valDelta)
            end
        )
    from jsonb_each(orig) e1(keyOrig, valOrig)
    full join jsonb_each(delta) e2(keyDelta, valDelta) on keyOrig = keyDelta
$$;
```

Comment: I've searched for this for hours into the night today... thanks a lot for this function, it definitelly saved me :)