# Merge duplicate PostgreSQL jsonb entries into one

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, jsonb

I am trying to merge together the 2 duplicates entries in the attached screenshot.
The primary key in this table is (email_address, census_key).

[image]

The last column type is jsonb and my expected final entry should look like in the following screenshot:

[image]

Wherever the keys are overlapping, the latest timestamp should be kept. Also, different keys should be merged together.

This is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE public.test
email_address character varying(256) NOT NULL,
census_key character varying(32) NOT NULL,
doc jsonb NOT NULL
```

These are the insert queries that I've run:

```
INSERT INTO public.test(
email_address, census_key, doc)
VALUES ('test', 'test_key', '{"jsonmap":{"1": 1526899328, "2": 
1526800040}}');

INSERT INTO public.test(
email_address, census_key, doc)
VALUES ('TEST', 'test_key', '{"jsonmap":{"1": 1526888354, "3": 
1521123440}}');
```

Is there a way of doing this in a PSQL query? Can you please point me in the right direction?

Many, many thanks!

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101603/merging-concatenating-jsonb-columns-in-query

Comment: please post actual data & schema, not screenshots

Comment: why didn't you vote close this answer as a duplicate? @KaushikNayak

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging Concatenating JSON(B) columns in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101603/merging-concatenating-jsonb-columns-in-query)

Comment: @RaymondNijland : Did now.. Thanks!