# Invalid input syntax for type JSON

Tags: node.js, postgresql

This query gets syntax error:

```
var querydb = `INSERT INTO msg_conversations VALUES (DEFAULT, ${user_id}, null, null, null, null, '{"key": "value", "unique": "' || uuid_generate_v4() || '"}'::jsonb, to_timestamp('05 Dec 2000', 'DD Mon YYYY'), to_timestamp('05 Dec 2000', 'DD Mon YYYY') )`

db.sequelize.query(querydb)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

first convert to text then convert to jsonb

train this tips by select statemant:

```
select  ('{"key": "value", "unique": "asdas'||to_timestamp( '05 Dec 2000', 'DD Mon YYYY' )||'"}' ::TEXT)::jsonb
```

`||` only use for text type

then for your problem :

```
var querydb = `INSERT INTO msg_conversations VALUES (DEFAULT, ${user_id}, null, null, null, null, ('{"key": "value", "unique": "' || uuid_generate_v4() || '"}'::TEXT)::jsonb, to_timestamp('05 Dec 2000', 'DD Mon YYYY'), to_timestamp('05 Dec 2000', 'DD Mon YYYY') )`
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll pick you the best answer. Do you know beside from `uuid_generate_v4`, there is any solution to create a Unique Indexes or Unique ID for JSONB field, bro?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530736/how-can-i-generate-a-unique-string-per-record-in-a-table-in-postgres

Comment: in postgres or js?

Comment: There is no point in using `::TEXT`; you are casting text to text. You seem to be basing this on posts like [Merging Concatenating JSON(B) columns in query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30101603), where the input is a jsonb column.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The problem is not having parentheses. castings are only for educational purposes , to show output of each part