# How to iterate JSON object with same key

Tags: javascript, json

I have a API response, which is like the below code

```
const res = {

"a" : {},
"a" : {}

}
```

Comment: I don't think this is valid JSON.

Comment: This is invalid json. `Error: Duplicate key 'a'` will be shown

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40956189/691711

Comment: I know this is a invalid JSON. But is there any way to iterate it ?

Comment: Can you possibly make the key unique before parsing the JSON?

Comment: @NaveenKumar: not that I know of. https://jsfiddle.net/codeandcloud/zd1awtms/

Comment: Is this this full API response? In my experience, it usually ends up as an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. In JSON, there is no error if you use the same name for multiple keys, but the last key with the same name will be used. I suggest using an array for the values for a key.

E.g.:

```
const res = {
    "a" : {},
    "a" : {}
}
```

would be

```
const res = {
    "a" : [{}, {}]
}
```

Then you could iterate on the list.

Answer (score 0):

if "a" isn't used to identify it's value, it shouldn't be a key. You could restructure you JSON to look like this:

```
const res = [
  ["a", {}],
  ["a", {}]
]
```

and then iterate over it using:

```
for(let [k,v] of res)
  print(k,v)
```