# rename duplicate key in json file python

Tags: python, json

I have json file which has duplicate keys.

Example

```
{
  "data":"abc",
  "data":"xyz"
}
```

I want to make this as 
    {
      "data1":"abc",
      "data2":"xyz"
    }

I tried using object_pairs_hook with json_loads, but it is not working. Could anyone one help me with Python solution for above problem

Comment: When you will consume that json, there will be no duplicates. Because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object

Comment: That's quite a strange requirement. Wouldn't you prefer `{"data": ["abc", "xyz"]}`?

Comment: Also, how did you get such a file? Can you not fix the source?

Comment: @AlexHall the input is not under my control. It is coming from different source. Hence I faced this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the `load` method a keyword parameter to handle pairing, there you can check for duplicates like this:

```
raw_text_data = """{
  "data":"abc",
  "data":"xyz",
  "data":"xyz22"
}"""
def manage_duplicates(pairs):
    d = {}
    k_counter = Counter(defaultdict(int))
    for k, v in pairs:
        d[k+str(k_counter[k])] = v
        k_counter[k] += 1

    return d

print(json.loads(raw_text_data, object_pairs_hook=manage_duplicates))
```

I used `Counter` to count each key, if it already exists, I'm saving the key as `k+str(k_counter[k)` - so it will be added with a trailing number.

**P.S**

If you have control on the input, I would highly recommend to change your json structure to:

```
{"data": ["abc", "xyz"]}
```

[The rfc 4627 for `application/json` media type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-2.2) recommends unique keys but it doesn't forbid them explicitly:

> The names within an object SHOULD be unique.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It worked for me. As I do not have control over input, I could not change json structure

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution using [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

```py
import re

s = '{ "data":"abc", "data":"xyz", "test":"one", "test":"two", "no":"numbering" }'

def find_dupes(s):
    keys = re.findall(r'"(\w+)":', s)
    return list(set(filter(lambda w: keys.count(w) > 1, keys)))

for key in find_dupes(s):
    for i in range(1, len(re.findall(r'"{}":'.format(key), s)) + 1):
        s = re.sub(r'"{}":'.format(key), r'"{}{}":'.format(key, i), s, count=1)

print(s)
```

Prints this string:

```
{
    "data1":"abc",
    "data2":"xyz",
    "test1":"one",
    "test2":"two",
    "no":"numbering"
}
```

Comment: This will be fail if the user has more than just `data` dup keys

Comment: @OrDuan that's true, but OP asked for a simple substitution. If a universal solution was needed, I'd take my time. Nonetheless, thanks for feedback!

Comment: @BrightOne thanks for the solution. As OrDuan mentioned it will fail if i provide more than just data duplicate keys. Could you please help address this issue

Comment: Edited. *gosh, this is so ugly*

Comment: @BrightOne thanks for the updated answer. It is still giving one issue. It is not working for nested objects. It is working only for outer objects.

Comment: @AmeyaKulkarni as for me, it works just the same for nested objects. I'll take a look