# How to merge duplicate keys in a json using java

Tags: java, json

My json looks like

```
 {
      "data": [
        {
         "location":"hjjh",
         "latitude":"56.65765",
         "longitude":"65.6576"
        }
             ],
     "data": [
        {
         "location":"thfh",
         "latitude":"67.65765",
         "longitude":"5.6576"
        }
            ]
    }
```

How could I merge the key of given json to single key as in below format using JAVA

```
{
  "data": [
    {
     "location":"hjjh",
     "latitude":"56.65765",
     "longitude":"65.6576"
    },
    {
     "location":"thfh",
     "latitude":"67.65765",
     "longitude":"5.6576"
    }
        ]
}
```

Same issue has been discussed in [combine duplicate keys in json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357405/combine-duplicate-keys-in-json)
Can anyone tell me the fix in java

Comment: Take a look on linked question. Use `Jackson` library in the newest version. Create two classes: `Locations` and `Location.` Class `Location` should have 3 fields: `location`, `latitude`, `longitude`. Class `Locations` should have `private List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<>();` and a method annotated with `@JsonAnySetter` annotation: `private void setLocations(String name, List<Location> values)`. In body just add all `values` to `locations`. After deserialising process you should have all data in collection.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which `JSON` library you are using, here comes a way by `Jackson` to achieve what you want.

First, create a class `Data` with only one member - `Map<String, List<Object>>` and for its setter, annotated by `@JsonAnySetter`. Then implements customized setter as follows:

**Class Data**

```java
class Data {
    private Map<String, List<Object>> map = new HashMap<>();
    public Map<String, List<Object>> getMap() {
        return map;
    }
    
    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setMap(String key, List<Object> value) {
        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            map.get(key).add(value.get(0));
        } else {
            map.put(key, Stream.of(value.get(0)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }
    }
}
```

**Code snippet**
After class `Data` is ready, you can deserialize your given JSON string with duplicate keys to `Data` and serialize it to expected JSON string by following code snippet.

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Data data = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, Data.class);
         
System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
        .writeValueAsString(data.getMap()));
```

**Console output**

```json
{
  "data" : [ {
    "location" : "hjjh",
    "latitude" : "56.65765",
    "longitude" : "65.6576"
  }, {
    "location" : "thfh",
    "latitude" : "67.65765",
    "longitude" : "5.6576"
  } ]
}
```