# How do I get the first of a duplicate element in a json?

Tags: json, python-3.x, wireshark

```
[
 {
  frame: {data,data}
  radiotap: {data,data}
  wlan: {data,data}
  wlan: {data,data}strong text
 }
]
```

This is a compressed example of a wireshark json I'm working with.  When I loop through the json using Python3 it only returns the last wlan element and I need the first.  How would I access the data in that element?

It also gets the second "wlan" element when I try direct access
ie print(json[0][wlan]), this returns the second wlan element.

Comment: The example is not in a valid JSON syntax. Looks more like a dictionary in python.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should not use duplicate keys.

[Does JSON syntax allow duplicate keys in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object)

But still you can use **JSONDecoder**:

```
from json import JSONDecoder


def met(a):
    return a


json="""{
  "frame": {"a": 10},
  "radiotap": {"b": 10},
  "wlan": {"c": 10},
  "wlan": {"d": 10}
 }
 """


for i in JSONDecoder(object_pairs_hook=met).decode(json):
    print(i)
```