# Is DuplicatePropertyNameHandling possible in Web Api?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

Is it possible to assign a global setting to `AddJsonOptions` to not allow duplicate values to be passed?

For example, if I send the following JSON I want the JSON not to validate.

```
{
    "firstName": "Bob",
    "firstName": "Smith",
    "firstName": "Bobby",
}
```

I'd assumed there would be a setting somewhere in `AddJsonOptions` somewhere but I can't find anything. I'd be happy to hear if this is possible any other way if not in `AddJsonOptions`.

Comment: I've found this other similar question that I'll have a look at:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55154252/how-to-validate-json-request-body-as-valid-json-in-asp-net-core/55161421#55161421

Comment: I think it does... i found it before you posted but not tried yet... thanks

Comment: Then you should accept the link as a duplicate which will close the question.