# How to throw an exception when member comes twice on Deserializing with JsonConvert

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, jsonconvert

I have JSON which contains duplicated members:

```
[
  {
    "MyProperty": "MyProperty1",
    "MyProperty": "MyWrongProperty1",
    "MyProperty2": "MyProperty12",
    "MyProperty2": "MyWrongProperty2"
  },
  {
    "MyProperty": "MyProperty21",
    "MyProperty2": "MyProperty22"
  }
]
```

When I deserialize, it is getting the last property. Here is the code:

```
var myJson = File.ReadAllText("1.txt");
List<MyClass> myClasses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(myJson);
```

But I need to throw an exception when JSON string contains duplicated properties. How can I do that?

Comment: Use a custom Converter using the `JsonConverter`. Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714160/how-to-deserialize-json-with-duplicate-property-names-in-the-same-object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deserialize JSON with duplicate property names in the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714160/how-to-deserialize-json-with-duplicate-property-names-in-the-same-object)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski this does not answer the question.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ Actully, it seems to be an exact duplicate, as well as many others questions on this site, which can be found by googling within few minutes (like [Json.NET (Newtonsoft.Json) - Two 'properties' with same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877526/json-net-newtonsoft-json-two-properties-with-same-name). One of the answers below shows the same approach with answers in duplicates

Comment: As I understand OP need to throw exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to added `DuplicatePropertyNameHandling = DuplicatePropertyNameHandling.Error` in your `JsonLoadSettings`.

You can dig in details following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55154252/how-to-validate-json-request-body-as-valid-json-in-asp-net-core/55161421#55161421).

There is also a thread from Newtonsoft.json that cover [this](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/931) topic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JsonTextReader` from `Newtonsoft.Json` to get all tokens which are of `PropertyName` and then probably use LINQ `GroupBy()` like

```
string json = "[
  {
    "MyProperty": "MyProperty1",
    "MyProperty": "MyWrongProperty1",
    "MyProperty2": "MyProperty12",
    "MyProperty2": "MyWrongProperty2"
  },
  {
    "MyProperty": "MyProperty21",
    "MyProperty2": "MyProperty22"
  }
]";

List<string> props = new List<string>();

JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json));
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.Value != null && reader.TokenType == "PropertyName")
    {
        props.Add(reader.Value);
    }
}
```

Now use `GroupBy()` on the list to see duplicates

```
var data = props.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => new 
           {
             PropName = x.Key,
             Occurence = x.Count()
           }).Where(y => y.Occurence > 1).ToList();

If (data.Any())
{
  Throw New Exception("Duplicate Property Found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject had that functionality in a older version but they removed it.
To provide an alternative they added a new option to the JsonLoadSettings - DuplicatePropertyNameHandling - that allows you to set up the desired behaviour.

Here you go:

```
            public object DeserializeObject(string json)
            {
                using (var stringReader = new StringReader(json))
                using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader))
                {

                    return JToken.ReadFrom(jsonReader, 
                        new JsonLoadSettings{ DuplicatePropertyNameHandling = DuplicatePropertyNameHandling.Error })
                        .ToObject<object>();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?