# my loop is only printing the second part of the dictionary , i'm using json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, loops

```
import json

data ='''
    {
   "names": {"first_boy" : "khaled"},
   "names": {"second_boy" : "waseem"}
    }
    '''
info = json.loads(data)
for line in info:
    print(info["names"])
```

I expected it to print the `first_boy` and the `second_boy` dictionary ,but it's printing

`{'second_boy': 'waseem'}`

Comment: The problem here is that you have 2 keys with the same name "names".

Comment: Also is there a specific reason you save the Dict as string and then turn it back to json? You can save it as json directly.

Answer (score 4):

Dicts in python can only support one of the same key. Similarly, [most implementations of JSON do not allow duplicate keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object). The way python handles this, when using `json.loads()` (or anything else that constructs a `dict`) is to simply use the most recent definition of any given key.

In this case, `{"second_boy":"waseem"}` overwrites `{"first_boy":"khaled"}`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the key "names" exists 2 times.
Maybe you can do this:

```
import json

data ='''
    {
   "names": {"first_boy" : "khaled",
             "second_boy" : "waseem"}
    }
    '''
info = json.loads(data)
for key, value in info['names'].items():
    print(key, value)
```

Comment: Suggestion to make it a more complete example:

for key,value in info['names'].items():
    print(key, value)

Comment: @Hkoof Thanks for the suggestion, you are right, should be a better answer now. Thanks!