# Validate if view model is only being passed once in an api through fluent API

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I am using Fluent API to validate the payload in my API. Street Address/MailingAddress/Lockbox Address are three different properties in the domain model. I want to make sure in my validation that Street address and mailing address is only passed once.

Correct Payload

```
{
"id" :123,
"name":"test",
"streetAddress": {
"city":"London",
"address":"q23"
},
"MailingAddress": {
"city":"NewYork",
"address":"q2453"
},
"LockBoxAddress": {
"city":"Miami",
"address":"q23888"
}
}
```

Domain Model

```
public string id{get;set;}
public string name{get;set;}
public Address streetAddress{get;set;}
public Address MailingAddress{get;set;}
public Address LockboxAddress{get;set;}
```

Incorrect Payload

```
{
"id" :123,
"name":"test",
"streetAddress": {
"city":"London",
"address":"q23"
},
"streetAddress": {
"city":"NewYork",
"address":"q2453"
}
}
```

I would like the above payload to error out by saying you cannot pass multiple street addresses and I am using Fluent API

Fluent API

```
RuleFor(x => x.streetAddress).Count(x =>x < 2).When(x => x.streetAddress!= null);
```

There is no property to get the count for the model. Any Ideas?

Comment: In the first place, why would you even have duplicated keys in a JSON string/object? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object

Comment: Are you working with asp.net-core or asp.net?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo .net core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can't make it via Fluent validation API. Because there'll be **only one `streetAddress` property** in your domain model **after** the payload deserialization. On the other hand, your code `RuleFor(x => x.streetAddress)` returns `IRuleBuilderInitial<XModel, Address>` instead of `IRuleBuilderInitial<XModel, IList<Address>>`. To achieve your goal, you should make sure your validation happens **before** FluentValidation, i.e., **validate the payload when deserializing** .
2. Sometimes a client might send a json with duplicated keys, if you're using `ASP.NET Core 2.1` or `ASP.NET 2.2`, it **won't fail by default**.

**How to solve**

To reject such a payload, make sure your version of `Newtonsoft.Json` is **`12.0.1` or higher**. If you're not sure, just add such a reference in your `*.csproj`:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.1" />
```

And then create a custom Model Binder to handle duplicated keys:

```cs
public class RejectDuplicatedKeysModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private JsonLoadSettings _loadSettings  = new JsonLoadSettings(){ DuplicatePropertyNameHandling = DuplicatePropertyNameHandling.Error };

    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext)); }
        var modelName = bindingContext.BinderModelName ?? bindingContext.OriginalModelName ?? bindingContext.FieldName ?? String.Empty;
        var modelType = bindingContext.ModelType;

        var req = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var raw = req.Body;
        if (raw == null) {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(modelName, "invalid request body stream");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(raw));
        try {
            var json = (JObject)JToken.Load(reader, this._loadSettings);
            var o = json.ToObject(modelType);
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(o);
        }
        catch (JsonReaderException e) {
            var msg = $"wrong property with key='{e.Path}': {e.Message}";
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(modelName, msg); 
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
        } 
        catch(Exception e) {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(modelName, e.ToString()); // you might want to custom the error info
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

By this way, the duplicated error info will be added into `ModelState`.

**Test Case**

Let's create a action method for test:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Test([ModelBinder(typeof(RejectDuplicatedKeysModelBinder))]XModel model){
    if(! this.ModelState.IsValid){
        var problemDetails = new ValidationProblemDetails(this.ModelState)
        {
            Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest,
        };
        return BadRequest(problemDetails);
    }
    return new JsonResult(model);
}
```

When there's a json with duplicated keys, we'll get an error like:
[image]