# Php array to json creator

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array and I want to convert array to json with php.

But my json_encode() function is that output:

```
$array = [
     'styles' => ['style'=>[]]
     ]; 


 {
     "stlyes":{
       "style":{
             0:{},
             1:{}
      }

}} 

//But it must be such
 {
     "stlyes":{
       "style":{},
       "style":{}

}}
```

Comment: Please post the code to let us view how you use `json_encode`

Comment: Share your code so that we can look for the solution.

Comment: Your wanted output is not valid json.

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object

Comment: Okay I know json structure but my service works as my example. My solution is send to service one by one, in this instance service has bulk request