# Decode dictionary with identical keys from json in Swift

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, codable

I have a struct that I describe in a JSON file, say the struct is named `Dog`

```
struct Dog {
  var color: UIColor
}
```

I'm keeping track of my dogs in a dictionary in a JSON file where each dog's name act as an identifier.
So I could have the next JSON:

```
"myDogs": {

  "goodBoy": {
    "color": "#000000"
  },

  "veryGoodBoy": {
    "color": "#FFFFFF
  }

}
```

To descrive my 2 dogs, it being a dictionary I (obviously) want to avoid duplicate keys, so I would expect that when I decode `myDogs` that is of type `[String: Dog]` if the JSON has 2 dogs with the same key (name) I would get some error.

To my surprise it's not happening, instead it just ignores all the dogs after the first one, i.e for this JSON

```
"myDogs": {

  "goodBoy": {
    "color": "#000000"
  },

  "veryGoodBoy": {
    "color": "#FFFFFF
  }

  "goodBoy": {
    "color": "#FF0000"
  }

}
```

I would get a dictionary with 2 dogs, one name "goodBoy" with black color, and another named "veryGoodBoy" with white color.

Is there a way to raise an exception (or at least log an error) in the decoding stage?

Thanks in advance.

*Edit*

[Does JSON syntax allow duplicate keys in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object) helps but it doesnt answer my question.
Basically I'm asking is there a way in Swift to raise an exception in the decoding stage without rewriting `JSONDecoder()`

Comment: a key shouldn't be repeated in your response

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does JSON syntax allow duplicate keys in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object)

Comment: The three-key JSON is not even valid. `JSONDecoder()` decodes two keys and ignores the duplicate. But actually it's the business of the server to avoid duplicate keys in a dictionary.

Comment: @Gereon thank you, this helped my understanding of JSON conventions. But it does not answer my question, is there a way in Swift to raise an exception in the decoding stage without rewriting `JSONDecoder()`?

Comment: I don't think there is, and I also don't think you can expect there to be one if the JSON in question is not obviously malformed, according to the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you want to know if there is a way of detecting the duplicate key error with `JSONDecoder`.

Honestly I didn't know the answer so I investigated a bit.

### 1. Let's fix your JSON keeping the duplicate key inconsistency

Your input JSON has several errors besides the duplicate key.

1. A JSON should being with `{` or `]` and ending with the same symbol as well
2. There is a missing `"` at the end of "#FFFFFF
3. There is a missing `,` at the end of

```
  "veryGoodBoy": {
    "color": "#FFFFFF
  }
```

Let's apply these fixes and we finally get a JSON where the only error is the duplicate key

```
let data = """
{
    "myDogs": {

      "goodBoy": {
        "color": "#000000"
      },

      "veryGoodBoy": {
        "color": "#FFFFFF"
      },

      "goodBoy": {
        "color": "#FF0000"
      }
    }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!
```

### 2. The Codable struct

Now we can define a `Codable` type (I usually prefer a struct when decoding JSONs) to match the input JSON

```
struct Response: Decodable {

    let myDogs: [String: Dog]

    struct Dog: Decodable {
        let color: String
    }
}
```

### 3. Decoding

Finally let's try decoding the JSON

```
do {
    let dict = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
    print(dict)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This code runs fine without raising an error.
But (of course) the resulting value has a missing entry

> Why did I say "of course"? Because Swift dictionaries cannot have duplicated keys.

```
Response(
    myDogs: [
        "goodBoy": Dog(color: "#000000"),
        "veryGoodBoy": Dog(color: "#FFFFFF")
    ]
)
```

### 4. Considerations

So as far as I can see, the answer to your question is: NO, we cannot detect a duplicate key in the original JSON with JSONDecoder.