# How to make json tree through group by json data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Please take a look at my current json.

```
[ 
 {"mode": "AR","fname": "ta","lname":"da","w_lng":"2.xx","w_lat":"1.xx"....},
 {"mode": "AR","fname": "ta","lname":"da","w_lng":"3.xx","w_lat": "4.xx"....},
 {"mode": "AR","fname": "ka","lname":"ja","w_lng":"6.xx","w_lat": "5.xx"....}
]
```

Now What I am looking for:

```
{
"mode": "AR",
"results": [
        {
        "fname": "ta",
        "lname": "da",
        "w_level": [
                    { "w_lng": "2.xx",
                      "w_lat": "1.xx"
                      "anothelevel":[........]
                    },
                    {"w_lng": "3.xx",
                     "w_lat": "4.xx"
                     "anothelevel":[........]
                    }
                  ]  
       }
       {
        "fname": "ka",
        "lname": "ja",
        "w_level": [
            {
                "w_lng": "x.xx",
                "w_lat": "x.xx"
                .....................
                    }
                  ]  
       }
     ]
  }
```

It is same as we do in SQL group by. suppose First group by world, then country, then city, then village etc. I was tried through group by. but the result is not my expected output. Please suggest me what should  I do.

Comment: JSON cannot have repeated keys, you need to think about restructuring your data.

Comment: @AZ_ actually you can : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object

Comment: @Raymond it's interesting to learn that technically you can, but I don't think it would be any use. If you parse the Json to a JavaScript object, it will just use the value of the last key.

Comment: @Raymond, you can have repeated keys when creating a JS Native object but you cannot have in a JSON. Please read through the stack answers you posted and understand the difference between `JSON` and `JS Native object.`

Comment: @Suman, you can use reduce function to group your JSON as per your requirement. Please have a look at my answer below. Hope it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

------At last I found solution-----------

```
const reduceArrayByKeys = (inArr, keys, restKey) => {
const reduced = inArr.reduce((prev, cur) => {
const copied = { ...cur }
keys.forEach(key => delete copied[key])
const existing = prev.find(item => keys.every(key => item[key] === cur[key]))
if (existing) {
    existing[restKey].push(copied)
} else {
    const newItem = {}
    keys.forEach(key => newItem[key] = cur[key])
    newItem[restKey] = [copied]
    prev.push(newItem)
}
return prev
}, [])

return reduced
}

const reduced = reduceArrayByKeys(inArr, ['mode'], 'results')
reduced.forEach(item => {
  const results = item.results
  item.results = reduceArrayByKeys(results, ['fname', 'lname'], 'w_level')

  item.results.forEach(child => {
   child.w_level = reduceArrayByKeys(child.w_level, ['w_lng', 'w_lat'], 
               'other')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):**

```js
const inArr = [{"mode":"AR","fname":"Kiran","lname":"Dash","w_lng": "1.23", "w_lat": "2.23"},{"mode":"AR1","fname":"Suman","lname":"Dash","w_lng": "3.23", "w_lat": "4.23"},{"mode":"AR","fname":"Raman","lname":"Dash","w_lng": "5.23", "w_lat": "6.23"},{"mode":"AR","fname":"Milan","lname":"Dash","w_lng": "7.23", "w_lat": "8.23"},{"mode":"AR1","fname":"Naman","lname":"Dash","w_lng": "8.23", "w_lat": "9.23"},{"mode":"AR2","fname":"Phulan","lname":"Dash","w_lng": "10.23", "w_lat": "11.23"}]

console.log(
  Object.values(inArr.reduce((item, currItem) => {

    var { mode, fname, lname } = currItem;

    if (!item[mode]) item[mode] = { mode, results: [] }; 
    
    let w_level = {};
    for (let key of Object.keys(currItem)) {
      if (key !== "fname" && key !== 'lname' && key !== 'mode') {
        w_level[key] = currItem[key];
      }
    }

    item[mode].results.push({fname: fname, lname: lname, w_level: [w_level]});
    return item;
  }, {}))
);
```

**Code walk through**:

Loop over the input array, and group into an object indexed by mode.
Create an object with a result array if the mode doesn't exist yet, and push to that array.

Note: For the sake of simplicity, I have done it to one level. Please use the same approach to create multiple levels if you want.

Comment: Same thing I already tried: let parse_groupby = [parseD.reduce((a, c) => (a[c.mode] = (a[c.mode] || []).concat(c), a), {})];
But do not understand multilevel.

Comment: If possible just add more one level.

Comment: @SumanDash You can use the exact same logic to go one level deep.

Comment: where I have to add multilevel ? do not understand how can I define object inside it.

Comment: @SumanDash I have modified the answer to add multilevel JSON as shown in your question. Followed the answer from ramratan. Hope that solves your problem

Comment: I have edited my question. Please take a look at. Your answer is not group by recursively. What will be happened when same fname and lastname  come again under same mode?

Comment: You are welcome. Glad that you found the solution. Since your problem is solved, pls close this post by marking one of the answers as the correct one or posting your solution in the answers and mark it as correct. Cheers! Happy Weekend

Answer (score 1):

```
objMap = {};
for (let temp of obj) {
  if (!objMap[temp.mode]) {
    objMap[temp.mode] = { mode: temp.mode, results: [] }
  }
  let tempObj = { w_level: [], fname: temp.fname, lname: temp.lname };
  let w_level = {};
  for (let key of Object.keys(temp)) {
    if (key !== "fname" && key !== 'lname' && key !== 'mode') {

      w_level[key] = temp[key];

    }


  }
  tempObj.w_level.push(w_level)
  objMap[temp.mode].results.push(tempObj)
}


NOTE:get object by using Object.values(objMap);
```