# Multiple keys with same value in javascript object

Tags: javascript

so I'm trying to replicate an HTTP payload which has two same keys with different values.

```
const x = {};
x['house'] = 'table';
x['house'] = 'food';
```

The above doesnt work. Is there another alternative?

Comment: "HTTP payload" do you mean JSON?

Comment: You need an array of values `x['house'] = ['table', 'food']`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does JSON syntax allow duplicate keys in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object)

Comment: Use a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object or a [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object

Answer (score 5):

The usual way to do that is to use an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

```
const x = {};
x.house = ["table", "food"];
```

Or

```
const x = {
    house: ["table", "food"]
};
```

You could also use a `Set`:

```
const x = {
    house: new Set()
};
x.house.add("table");
x.house.add("food");
```

or

```
const x = {
    house: new Set(["table", "food"])
};
```

---

I've used dot notation above, but you can use brackets notation as you did in your question if you prefer:

```
const x = {};
x["house"] = ["table", "food"];
```

Comment: If the HTTP payload has duplicate keys, wouldn't it be better to use a string, and then parse it?

Comment: This doesn't quite work for me because I need the two values to be in a separate key with the same name

Comment: @MiguelBetancourt - What's the use case? (I can't think of one.) It's impossible to have two properties in the same JavaScript object with the same name, and a JavaScript property can have only **one** value, so it's a matter of using that one value to refer to multiple things, whether that's an array, another plain object, an object like a Set, a string you parse as evolutionxbox mentioned, or a `FormData` object as Titus mentioned, etc.

Comment: I'm trying to simulate a POST request with a payload which has two keys with the same name but a different value

Comment: @MiguelBetancourt - That just doesn't exist in JavaScript (other than as described 
 above). (`FormData` gets you close.) For example, JavaScript-based server-side mechanisms for receiving HTTP requests give you arrays for repeated parameters; [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions).