# how to stop ignoring jObject properties when we call API?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm calling API using postman, I'm sending dynamic properties using JObject as given below

I'm sending class data to API using JSON but which is ignoring the values of duplicate data

```cs
     public class Details
        { 
            public List<JObject> Mappings { get; set; } 

             // adding properties to jobject abd mappings     

            [JsonExtensionData]
            public IDictionary<string, JToken> AdditionalProperties { get; set; }

         }
```

I'm using below JSON in postman

```
    {      
      "source": {
            "details": "Sample Customer",
            "compoet": "Sample Site",
            "Name": "Sample Software",
            "Version": "1.0.1",
            "Creator": "Sample Company"
        },
      "Mappings":[
      {
        "data": Test.Name1",
        "data": Test.Name23",    
        "newprop":"Account1",
      }
    {
        "data": "Test.Name2",    
        "newprop":"Account2",
      }
    ]
    }
```

when I pass duplicate key API is taking second value `"data": Test.Name23"` I want API should take both values from mapping can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's better don't do that, and this is [my reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23195243/10422410)

you can pass "data" value as an array

Comment: Thank you, In my case, User may pass a duplicate object to API  i need to throw the error after verification, but API itself not receiving the duplicate properties. is it possible to allow duplicates?

Comment: you can catch that exception with middleware then do what you need with that. it means you can define a middleware and handle that exception in your own way

Comment: Middleware in the sense, let's say user using the postman to hit my API controller, where can I build the middleware, and when I receive the data in the controller itself which is removing the duplicate data, do we have any JSON settings to validate this kind of issue?

Comment: no there is not any setting, also you can get your json as a string from your client. then validate it in your controller

Comment: Thank you, can we throw the exception if we pass duplicate values to API before sends, is there any filter or overrides to catch the entire object

Comment: when you get your json as string? yes we can throw

Comment: Sure let me try, can we pass same object as a string as well as to object to API call at the same time.