# Json and Guava Multimap

Tags: jackson, guava

I would like to create a multimap, convert it to JSON and back again. The problem here is, that single values still shown as collection/array.

Here is what I have

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new GuavaModule());    

Multimap<String, String> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();    
map.put("Cheesecake", "mummy");
map.put("Cookie", "PHPSESSID=298zf09hf012fh2; csrftoken=u32t4o3tb3gg43");
map.put("Cookie", "yummy_cookie=choco; tasty_cookie=strawberry");

System.out.println(map);
System.out.println("---");

String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(map);
System.out.println("JSON:");
System.out.println(json);  
System.out.println("---");   

JsonNode node = objectMapper.readTree(json);
Multimap<String, String> multimap = objectMapper.readValue(
objectMapper.treeAsTokens(node),
objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapLikeType(
Multimap.class, String.class, String.class));
System.out.println(multimap);
```

Output:

```
{Cookie=[PHPSESSID=298zf09hf012fh2; csrftoken=u32t4o3tb3gg43, yummy_cookie=choco; tasty_cookie=strawberry], Cheesecake=[mummy]}
---
JSON:
{"Cookie":["PHPSESSID=298zf09hf012fh2; csrftoken=u32t4o3tb3gg43","yummy_cookie=choco; tasty_cookie=strawberry"],"Cheesecake":["mummy"]}
---
{Cookie=[PHPSESSID=298zf09hf012fh2; csrftoken=u32t4o3tb3gg43, yummy_cookie=choco; tasty_cookie=strawberry], Cheesecake=[mummy]}
```

I would like to have sth like:

```
JSON:
{"Cookie":["PHPSESSID=298zf09hf012fh2; csrftoken=u32t4o3tb3gg43","yummy_cookie=choco; tasty_cookie=strawberry"],"Cheesecake":"mummy"}
//or even better 
JSON:
{"Cookie":"PHPSESSID=298zf09hf012fh2; csrftoken=u32t4o3tb3gg43","Cookie":"yummy_cookie=choco; tasty_cookie=strawberry","Cheesecake":"mummy"}
```

So "mummy" is a string value instead inside json array.

---

Any idea how to archive this?

Comment: Regarding the last format, where the "Cookie" key is repeated: Be aware that may json parsers do not support duplicate keys. This link has more comments about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Multimpap#asMap()`](https://guava.dev/releases/28.2-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#asMap--) view and serialize it with [`SerializationFeature.WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED) to achieve the first out of your desired formats. Note that you'd need [`DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY) to deserialize map-like object with this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new GuavaModule());
objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED);

Multimap<String, String> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();
map.put("Cheesecake", "mummy");
map.put("Cookie", "PHPSESSID=298zf09hf012fh2; csrftoken=u32t4o3tb3gg43");
map.put("Cookie", "yummy_cookie=choco; tasty_cookie=strawberry");

System.out.println(map);
System.out.println("---");

String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(map.asMap());
System.out.println("JSON:");
System.out.println(json);
System.out.println("---");

JsonNode node = objectMapper.readTree(json);
Multimap<String, String> multimap = objectMapper.readValue(
        objectMapper.treeAsTokens(node),
        objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapLikeType(
                Multimap.class, String.class, String.class));
System.out.println(multimap);
```

Output:

```
{Cookie=[PHPSESSID=298zf09hf012fh2; csrftoken=u32t4o3tb3gg43, yummy_cookie=choco; tasty_cookie=strawberry], Cheesecake=[mummy]}
---
JSON:
{"Cookie":["PHPSESSID=298zf09hf012fh2; csrftoken=u32t4o3tb3gg43","yummy_cookie=choco; tasty_cookie=strawberry"],"Cheesecake":"mummy"}
---
{Cookie=[PHPSESSID=298zf09hf012fh2; csrftoken=u32t4o3tb3gg43, yummy_cookie=choco; tasty_cookie=strawberry], Cheesecake=[mummy]}
```

If you want to serialize and deserialize second desired format, you need to [write custom Jackson serializer / deserializer](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers).