# Parse list of tuples/maps into structs with serde-yaml

Tags: rust, yaml, serde

I would like to parse the following part of a `.yaml`-file:

```
networks:
  foo1: 192.168.1.0/24
  bar1: 192.168.2.0/24
  foo2: 2001:CAFE:1::/64
  bar2: 2001:CAFE:2::/64
```

... where the key of each property is the labels the name of a network and the value indicates the assigned subnet to it.
The deserialized structs should look like the following:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Networks {
    networks: Vec<Network>
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Network {
    name: String,
    subnet: String,
}
```

I would prefer this notation over

```
networks:
  - name: foo1
    subnet: 192.168.1.0/24
  - ...
```

since this would add unnecessary boilerplate. The problem is that I cannot properly parse this list of networks into structs, since to my current knowledge, the property of a struct has to have an equivalent key to it - and since the key-names here are "random" I cannot do that.

The only other workaround I've found is parsing the entries as HashMaps and automatically convert those into tuples of (String, String) (networks would then be a Vec<(String, String)>) via the [serde-tuple-vec-map](https://crates.io/crates/serde-tuple-vec-map) crate (which loses the named parameters).

This seems like something that would be easy to configure, yet I haven't found any solutions elsewhere.

Comment: This is theoretically possible but requires a custom deserializer for the `Vec`, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing a custom deserializer and using it with `#[serde(deserialize_with = "network_tuples")] networks: Vec<Network>` is one way of doing it:

```
fn network_tuples<'de, D>(des: D) -> Result<Vec<Network>, D::Error>
where
    D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
{
    struct Vis(Vec<Network>);
    impl<'de> serde::de::Visitor<'de> for Vis {
        type Value = Vec<Network>;
        fn expecting(&self, _formatter: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
            todo!("return nice descriptive error")
        }

        fn visit_map<A>(mut self, mut map: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error>
        where
            A: serde::de::MapAccess<'de>,
        {
            while let Some((name, subnet)) = map.next_entry()? {
                self.0.push(Network { name, subnet });
            }
            Ok(self.0)
        }
    }

    des.deserialize_map(Vis(vec![]))
}
```

You could do without the visitor by first deserializing to a `HashMap<String, String>` and then converting, but that has a performance penalty and you'd lose the ability to have two networks with the same name (not sure if you want that though).

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=952fb8bd4b71ded054145b1ed81e64b6)

---

Of course, you could also combine my favorite serde trick [`#[serde(from = "SomeStructWithVecStringString")]`](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#from) with the `serde-tuple-vec-map` crate. But I've already written many answers using `from`, so I'll refer to an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72483890/how-to-rename-start-and-end-range-values-with-serde/72484362#72484362).

Comment: (Different question, but the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64405600/how-can-i-deserialize-json-that-has-duplicate-keys-without-losing-any-of-the-val/64406395#64406395=) is rather similar.)