# Duplicate column in json file throws error when creating Spark External Table

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When trying to create a Spark SQL table reading from a JSON file, it fails with the below error
**Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Found duplicate column(s) in the data schema: `filename`**

As I understand this issue is related to Spark runtime and an alternative approach suggested for dataframes is [Duplicate column in json file throw error when creating PySpark dataframe Databricks after upgrading runtime 7.3LTS(Spark3.0.1) to 9.1LTS(Spark3.1.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69985305/duplicate-column-in-json-file-throw-error-when-creating-pyspark-dataframe-databr/70101218#70101218?newreg=bf23c8be29c741f2a2827b643166a312)

Looking for a similar alternative for SparkSQL table.
I tried to emulate it for spark table creation but not sure how to call out schema while creating table, any help is highly appreciated.

Note: My need is to create an external table in databricks pointing to JSON file which has duplicate column(s) issue.

I am creating a sql table as below which is resulting in the error because the json file has some duplicate column
[code_snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wU5Gj.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added a code snippet