# Dynamic JSON Schema Validation

Tags: python, validation, jsonschema

In Python 3.8, I'm trying to mock up a validation JSON schema for the structure below:

```
{
    # some other key/value pairs
    "data_checks": {
        "check_name": {
            "sql": "SELECT col FROM blah",
            "expectations": {
                "expect_column_values_to_be_unique": {
                    "column": "col",
                },
                # additional items as required
            }
        },
        # additional items as required
    }
}
```

The requirements I'm trying to enforce include:

- At least one item in `data_checks` that can have a dynamic name. Item keys should be unique.
- `sql` and `expectations` keys must be present
- `sql` should be a text string
- At least one item in `expectations`. Item keys should be unique.
- Within `expectations`, item keys must be equal to available methods provided by `dir(class_name)`

More advanced capability would include:

- Enforcing `expectations` method items to only include `kwargs` for that method

I currently have the following JSON schema for the `data_checks` portion:

```
"data_checks": {
    "description": "Data quality checks against provided sources.",
    "minProperties": 1,
    "type": "object",
    "patternProperties": {
        ".+": {
            "required": ["expectations", "sql"],
            "sql": {
                "description": "SQL for data quality check.",
                "minLength": 1,
                "type": "string",
            },
            "expectations": {
                "description": "Great Expectations function name.",
                "minProperties": 1,
                "type": "object",
                "anyOf": [
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "minLength": 1,
                        "pattern": [e for e in dir(SqlAlchemyDataset) if e.startswith("expect_")],
                    }
                ],
            },
        },
    },
},
```

This JSON schema does not enforce `expectations` to have at least one item nor does it enforce valid method names for the nested keys as expected from `[e for e in dir(SqlAlchemyDataset) if e.startswith("expect_")]`. I haven't really looked into enforcing `kwargs` for the selected method (is that even possible?).

I don't know if this is related to things being nested, but how would I enforce the proper validation requirements?

Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you can post some sort of an attempt so we can take it ahead from there. You should be able to do the unique key checks just by `json.loads` since duplicate keys are invalid JSON, unless you want a pure string parsing JSON schema validator.

Comment: JSON schema doesn't seem to be catching things as expected, so I don't know what to share. For example, if I put a method key name I know doesn't exist for a class, `jsonschema.validate` doesn't complain and the error is raised from the class object itself.

Comment: "duplicate keys are invalid JSON" - That's simply not true. See 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23195243/89211 - It's not good or advisable, but possible. json.loads will not throw an error.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could update your question with your current situaiton and problem.