# List to a json object

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services

I have a list of  ec2 instanceID like below:

```
['i-111111111111', 'i-22222222222']
```

And I want to convert it to json.

```json
{
  "instance_id": "i-111111111111",
  "instance_id": "i-222222222222"
}
```

Can someone please advise how to do it in Python?

Comment: What did you try? Also it does not really make sense to have duplicate keys.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object

Comment: Thanks for feedback @Marcin @jhilmer
Actually I will be using this script for terraform external data source. That is why I'm using a single key(instance_id) because it be used in output section. 
`output "instance_id_list" {   value = data.external.get_instanceid_using_python.result.instance_id }`
Do you have better approach on this? Sorry I'm new to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
li = ['i-111111111111', 'i-22222222222']
di = dict()
for i in li:
   a = {'instance_id':i}
   di.update(a)
print(di)
```

But having a single key is not a good approach

Comment: Thanks for feedback @GeekGroot

Actually I will be using this script for  terraform external data source.
That is why I'm using a single key(instance_id) because it be used in output section.

`output "instance_id_list" {
  value = data.external.get_instanceid_using_python.result.instance_id
}`

Do you have better approach on this?
Sorry I'm new to python.