# How to bring the elements under different nodes onto one common node in JSON using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

Here is sample JSON data. It has one 'PO' and inside 'PO' there are multiple 'SO' nodes. Inside an 'SO' node there can be multiple nodes each containing one 'B', 'R', 'F'.

```
{
    "PO": [
        {
            "SO": [
                {
                    "B": "XXX",
                    "R": "YYY",
                    "F": "ZZZ"
                },
                {
                    "B": "MMM",
                    "R": "NNN",
                    "F": "PPP"
                }
            ],
            "SO": [
                {
                    "B": "111",
                    "R": "222",
                    "F": "333"
                },
                {
                    "B": "333",
                    "R": "444",
                    "F": "555"
                },
                {
                    "B": "666",
                    "R": "777",
                    "F": "888"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want this data to be like this

```
{
    "PO": [
        {
            "B": "XXX",
            "R": "YYY",
            "F": "ZZZ"
        },
        {
            "B": "MMM",
            "R": "NNN",
            "F": "PPP"
        },
        {
            "B": "111",
            "R": "222",
            "F": "333"
        },
        {
            "B": "333",
            "R": "444",
            "F": "555"
        },
        {
            "B": "666",
            "R": "777",
            "F": "888"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I do this in Javascript?

I tried `obj.PO[0].SO` where obj is the JSON object and some replace functions to replace the 'SO' nodes, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: you can not have more than one key with the same name.

Comment: You have duplicate keys in your input JSON. This means one value will overwrite the other.

Comment: @NinaScholz I see. I am new to JSON. But I got the file from the source this way i.e. there are multiple keys with the same name. How do I solve this?

Comment: Tell the source that the file is invalid?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your JSON contains duplicate keys. This means that when `JSON.parse` converts the JSON string into an object, one value will override the other, and as such you will obtain either

```json
{
    "PO": [
        {
            "SO": [
                {
                    "B": "XXX",
                    "R": "YYY",
                    "F": "ZZZ"
                },
                {
                    "B": "MMM",
                    "R": "NNN",
                    "F": "PPP"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

or

```json
{
    "PO": [
        {
            "SO": [
                {
                    "B": "111",
                    "R": "222",
                    "F": "333"
                },
                {
                    "B": "333",
                    "R": "444",
                    "F": "555"
                },
                {
                    "B": "666",
                    "R": "777",
                    "F": "888"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

the ideal solution would be to have your input be proper JSON without key collisions; as a workaround, you can instead use an event-based ("SAX style") JSON parser such as [`clarinet`](https://github.com/dscape/clarinet) to preserve all information.