# How do I return a JSON object with duplicate keys in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I'm running into an issue I don't know how to resolve. I need to return a JSON object that has duplicate keys.

I understand this is perfectly valid according to the JSON specification. See [ecma-404](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-404/#page=11), page 6 that reads:

> The JSON syntax does not impose any restrictions on
> the strings used as names, does not require that name strings be unique...

I need to return this:

```
{
  "id":"1401",
  "sku":"C18-25",
  "sku":"A15-70"
}
```

I've been using a typical rest method in Spring Boot:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> getProduct(@PathVariable String id) {
  Map<String, String> r = new HashMap<>();
  r.put("id", "1401");
  r.put("sku", "C18-25");
  r.put("sku", "A15-70");
  return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>>(r, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

But it only keeps the last entry:

```
{
  "id":"1401",
  "sku":"A15-70"
}
```

How can I return multiple entries with the same name?

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: [The specs tell you that you](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-4) that names within an object SHOULD be unique. SHOULD is not MUST, but it is _highly_ recommended you follow that advice. It can lead to trouble with many tools. Why not make `sku` an array?

Comment: That’s non-sensical—any reasonable parsing would keep only the last value. At **best** you could hope for an object that converts keys with multiple values into a collection, but that’s problematic for the consuming code.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Unfortunately, it is valid JSON (see reference to the standard) and it's a requirement I need to deal with. Sigh.

Comment: The topic regarding duplicate keys was already discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/23195243/224155

Comment: @DaveNewton I understand but names can be duplicated in JSON. See reference to the standard.

Comment: @Ivar Taking aside what is the best option, do you know if Spring Boot support this or not?

Comment: @JoeDiNottra If you're going down the unrecommended road anyway, you might as well break the unwritten "never manually construct JSON" rule. Just construct the JSON yourself and return it as a String. I doubt any of the built-in serializers allow you to generate a JSON with duplicate keys. But honestly, sometimes you have to sell "no" as a software engineer. If someone asks you to break a diamond with your bare hands, then saying  "welp, that's the requirement" isn't really an option either. It's just not feasible.

Comment: @Ivar Thank you. I think I'll push back. The client will fight it since "the standard says it's perfectly possible", but I guess it's much safer to avoid this in the long run. Bitter pill to swallow for the client (and for me as well, in consequence).

Comment: @JoeDiNottra I have to say that there are cases where one party requires some format, irrelevant of specs, an then you often don't have other options than to comply with that requirement if you want to get job done. This case here is far from being worst in that regard.

Comment: @JoeDiNottra I see, may bad, I was convinced that it's requirement (not a strong recommendation).

Comment: @JoeDiNottra I didn't say they couldn't--I said it's non-sensical because duplicate keys would delete data w/o warning, or at best, throw an error/warning.

Answer (score 1):

You can just return a string with response entity.

```
String response = "{\n"+
"  \"id\":\"1401\",\n"+
"  \"sku\":\"C18-25\",\n"+
"  \"sku\":\"A15-70\"\n"+
"}";
return new ResponseEntity<String>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
```

It is not pretty, but it is supported by Spring and will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

A `HashMap` only allows **unique** key values, so there is no way for you to use `HashMap` for this purpose. Also while you are correct, you *can* use duplicate key values in a JSON body, it is not recommended. Why not make `sku` an array like this?

```
"sku":["A15-70","C18-25"]
```

Comment: It's a requirement I need to deal with. If I cannot use a Map, what can I use?

Comment: I suppose you can try to manually create a JSON string for them and return that? Not ideal, but if you need to do it I guess it works.

Answer (score 0):

While creating map create like this

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

while putting existing key in Map check using ***containsKey()*** method and put duplicate value in ***List*** of key

you will get result like this

> {   "id":"1401",   "sku":["A15-70","C18-25"] }

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can construct a JSON-object from an arbitrary number of `Map.Entry` instances (*but obviously if JSON structure would be more complex it'll be better to avoid generating it manually at all costs since it would be tedious and error-prone*):

```
@SafeVarargs
public static String entriesToJson(Map.Entry<String, String>... entries) {
    
    return Arrays.stream(entries)
        .map(e -> "\t\"%s\" : \"%s\"".formatted(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(",\n", "{\n", "\n}"));
}

@GetMapping("/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> getProduct(@PathVariable String id) {
    // your logic
    return ResponseEntity.ok(
        entriesToJson(
            Map.entry("id", "1401"),
            Map.entry("sku", "C18-25"),
            Map.entry("sku", "A15-70")
        )
    );
}
```

*Usage example:*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(entriesToJson(
        Map.entry("id", "1401"),
        Map.entry("sku", "C18-25"),
        Map.entry("sku", "A15-70")
    ));
}
```

*Output:*

```
{
    "id" : "1401",
    "sku" : "C18-25",
    "sku" : "A15-70"
}
```