# Check for duplicate keys in a json file

Tags: python, json, continuous-integration, jq

I have a json file with the following contents:

```json
{
    "id1": {
        "key": "value"
    },
    "id2": {
        "key": "value"
    }
}
```

I want to check that each top level key ie. `id1, id2` is present only once in a file and if not produce an error. So something like

```json
{
    "id1": {
        "key": "value"
    },
    "id1": {
        "key": "value"
    }
}
```

must show as error.

Is there a way to do this with an json parsers like `jq` or `json-glib-validate`?

I came up with a pythonic solution, that works, but would be nicer to have an actual parser.

This is supposed to be used in CI.

```py
import collections
import json
import sys

def check_duplicates(pairs):
    count = collections.Counter(i for i,j in pairs)
    duplicates = ", ".join(i for i,j in count.items() if j>1)

    if len(duplicates) != 0:
        print("Duplicate keys found: {}".format(duplicates))
        sys.exit(1)

def validate(pairs):
    check_duplicates(pairs)
    return dict(pairs)

with open("file.json", "r") as file:
    try:
        obj = json.load(file, object_pairs_hook=validate)
    except ValueError as e:
        print("Invalid json: %s" % e)
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in a JSON structure by definition

Comment: @CtrlZ this one has, also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object

Comment: Then it's not JSON! If you use json.load() to parse that into a Python dictionary, one of the keys will be lost

Comment: You *can* have duplicate keys in `json`, but not in python `dict`s.

Comment: Yes I know that's why I had to come up with a checker like that.

Comment: If you run it, it'll say `python test.py 
Duplicate keys found: id1`

Comment: You solution seems ok, but I would merge `validate()` and `check_duplicates()` and raise a `KeyError` rather than do a `sys.exit()`.

Comment: OK - So duplicates *can* exist in a JSON structure **but** how would you propose to parse such a thing in Python?

Comment: @CtrlZ That's what my python script does, maybe you aren't looking

Comment: @JonSG I'm looking more for a json parser to do this than my custom script.

Comment: Sorry, but we can't recommend other software or libraries on SO.

Comment: The irony is that your code considers the existence of duplicate keys to be invalid

Comment: @CtrlZ yes that's what I'm trying to check... error on duplicate keys

Comment: Minor suggestion: `check_duplicates` should just raise an ordinary exception (possibly a subclass of `ValueError`)  rather than raising `SystemExit` (raised by `sys.exit`). The decision to actually exit the script should be made higher up the chain.

Comment: I'd also make `duplicates` a simple list of duplicated keys, and defer the call to `', '.join` until you construct the exception. `duplicates = [k for k, v in count.items() if v > 1]; if duplicates: raise KeyError(f"Duplicates: ', '.join(duplicates)")`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to do this with an json parsers like `jq`

You can use jq's stream representation, which can be called either via the `--stream` flag or via the `tostream` function. The difference is that for the function, the input has already been parsed (and duplicate keys collapsed), whereas using the flag would start streaming while reading the input, thus before any collapsing could occur. So, being in bash, for example, just compare the output of both, e.g. using `diff`:

```bash
$ diff -q <(jq --stream . nodupkeys.json) <(jq tostream nodupkeys.json)
# no output
```

```bash
$ diff -q <(jq --stream . withdupkeys.json) <(jq tostream withdupkeys.json)
Files /dev/fd/63 and /dev/fd/62 differ
```

---

Addressing @peak's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78021300#comment137547244_78021380): The approach above would fail if using [itchyny/gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq) instead of [jqlang/jq](https://github.com/jqlang/jq), as it automatically sorts the keys, but only after parsing the input (which is encountered when using the function, but not when using the flag), so for a document with unordered keys but without duplicates, it would still yield a difference.

The following (shell-free) approach tries to mitigate this by instead collecting all paths provided by the flag variant into an array, and then comparing its `sort`ed version with its `unique`d version (which is also automatically sorted), rendering irrelevant a potential sorting performed by the employed processor's implementation.

```bash
$ jq --stream -n '[inputs[-2] | arrays] | sort == unique' nodupkeys.json
true
```

```bash
$ jq --stream -n '[inputs[-2] | arrays] | sort == unique' withdupkeys.json
false
```

---

Addressing the discussion over duplicate keys being valid JSON or not:

From [ECMA-404: The JSON Data Interchange Standard](https://ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-404_2nd_edition_december_2017.pdf) (December 2017), section 6 "Objects":

> An object structure is represented as […] name/value pairs. A name is a *string*. […] The JSON syntax does not impose any restrictions on the *strings* used as names, does not require that name *strings* be unique, and does not assign any significance to the ordering of name/value pairs. These are all semantic considerations that may be defined by JSON processors […].

And from section 2 "Conformance":

> A conforming processor of JSON texts should not accept any inputs that are not conforming JSON texts. A conforming processor may impose semantic restrictions that limit the set of conforming JSON texts that it will process.

Thus, from a purely syntactical standopint (i.e. regarding the grammar, which is what these specs are all about), it is totally valid to have duplicate keys. As for the semantical side, though, (i.e. regarding the information conveyed according to a processor), processors are explicitly still "conforming" if they impose restrictions such as disallowing duplicate keys.

Meanwhile, [RFC 8259: The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange Format](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259) (also December 2017) is a little more recommending. It even states in section 1.2 "Specifications of JSON":

> Note, however, that ECMA-404 allows several practices that this specification recommends avoiding in the interests of maximal interoperability.

And, in fact, in section 4 "Objects", it essentially delivers the same message while explicitly advocating for the uniqueness of keys (using "SHOULD" as defined in [RFC 2119](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2119): "This word […] mean[s] that there may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a particular item, but the full implications must be understood and carefully weighed before choosing a different course."):

> An object structure is represented as […] name/value pairs (or members). A name is a string. […] The names within an object SHOULD be unique. […] When the names within an object are not unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is unpredictable. Many implementations report the last name/value pair only. Other implementations report an error or fail to parse the object, and some implementations report all of the name/value pairs, including duplicates.

Virtually all production-ready JSON processors I have played around with opted against refusing to parse a document containing duplicate keys, but at the same time they all performed some sort of collapsing to effectively make the keys unique.

So, in conclusion: duplicate keys are valid, but it has practical benefits to avoid, or at least not to rely on them. In this light, it makes perfect sense for the OP to find a way to spot them.

Comment: @peak Does it? I am not comparing two documents, just one with itself, so the order should be irrelevant as long as the document is processed in the order of its representation, which as of the latest releases of `jqlang/jq` (i.e. at least until v1.7) always was the case. `itchyny/gojq` admittedly breaks the approach as it automatically sorts the keys, but only *after* parsing, i.e. only when using the function. To be on the safe side, I added a pure (shell-free) solution with the actual comparison happening inside the jq/gojq filters using enforced sorting, so it should work in both.

Comment: @pmf what about `jq --stream 'select(length == 1 and (.[0]|length) == 2) | .[0][0]'` to list the top-level keys. That could be checked for dupes with shell tools. Is that a general solution, or just for the given sample?

Comment: @glenn This will only catch items the parser is backtracking to from one level deeper. Test it by inserting into your input a (duplicate or not) key with a scalar value or an empty iterable (which don't have a structure to backtrack from), e.g. `"id3": 42` or `"id4": {}`, and it won't show up in your output, regardless of how many times you use a given key for them.