# Merging all values under one key when there are duplicate keys

Tags: python, json, merge, duplicates

I have a JSON object where there are duplicate keys. I want to merge all the values as a string under one key using a ";" separator

input:

```
{
"1061": "GROCERY",
"1073": "GM-HBC",
"4220": "PRODUCE",
"958": "MEAT",
"958": "DAIRY",
"958": "FROZEN"
}
```

desired output:

```
{
"1061": "GROCERY",
"1073": "GM-HBC",
"4220": "PRODUCE",
"958": "MEAT;DAIRY;FROZEN"
}
```

I copied the question and data from this ([link](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D52T00006R4GJrSAN/i-have-a-json-where-there-are-duplicate-keys-i-want-to-merge-all-the-values-as-a-string-under-one-key-using-a-separator-1061-grocery-1073-gmhbc-4220-produce-958-meat-958-dairy-958-frozen)) since this is exactly what I'm looking for, except I want to do this in python.

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78021300/check-for-duplicate-keys-in-a-json-file#comment137546809_78021300 that uses `object_pairs_hook`

Comment: The JSON RFC strongly recommends against this practice, although it doesn't actually forbid it.  You should consider fixing whatever app is creating this data.  Given the above, it would be easy to change this to a list.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`json.loads(..., object_pairs_hook=...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
from itertools import groupby
import json

def merge_duplicates(pairs):
    for key, duplicate_pairs in groupby(sorted(pairs), lambda x: x[0]):
        yield key, ';'.join(value for _, value in duplicate_pairs)

def parse_with_duplicates(text):
    return json.loads(text, object_pairs_hook=lambda pairs: dict(merge_duplicates(pairs)))

print(parse_with_duplicates("""
{
"1061": "GROCERY",
"1073": "GM-HBC",
"4220": "PRODUCE",
"958": "MEAT",
"958": "DAIRY",
"958": "FROZEN"
}
"""))
# {'1061': 'GROCERY', '1073': 'GM-HBC', '4220': 'PRODUCE', '958': 'DAIRY;FROZEN;MEAT'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [multidict](https://multidict.aio-libs.org/en/stable/) library to create a MultiDict, which is like a regular dictionary but can hold multiple values for the same key.

```
import multidict

data = multidict.MultiDict([
   ("1061", "GROCERY"),
   ("1073", "GM-HBC"),
   ("4220", "PRODUCE"),
   ("958", "MEAT"),
   ("958", "DAIRY"),
   ("958", "FROZEN")
])

safe_dict = {}

for key in data.keys():
   safe_dict[key] = ";".join(data.getall(key))

print(safe_dict)

# {'1061': 'GROCERY', '1073': 'GM-HBC', '4220': 'PRODUCE', '958': 'MEAT;DAIRY;FROZEN'}
```

Comment: Might be helpful to show how to parse a MultiDict from a JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar solution to @BoppreH, but does not use `itertools`.

```py
import json
import pprint


def consolidate_duplicate_keys(list_of_pairs):
    # Add all values to a list
    result = dict()
    for k, v in list_of_pairs:
        result.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

    # Convert values from lists to strings
    result = {k: ";".join(v) for k, v in result.items()}
    return result


def main():
    json_text = """
    {
        "1061": "GROCERY",
        "1073": "GM-HBC",
        "4220": "PRODUCE",
        "958": "MEAT",
        "958": "DAIRY",
        "958": "FROZEN"
    }
    """
    obj = json.loads(json_text, object_pairs_hook=consolidate_duplicate_keys)
    pprint.pprint(obj)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
{'1061': 'GROCERY',
 '1073': 'GM-HBC',
 '4220': 'PRODUCE',
 '958': 'MEAT;DAIRY;FROZEN'}
```

Notes

The `setdefault()` method will create the key/value if the key does not exist in the dictionary. If the key already exists, it does not do anything. Further more, the `setdefault()` method returns the value corresponding to the key. Thus the code

```
result.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

is a shorthand for

```
if k not in result:
    result[k] = []
result[k].append(v)
```

Comment: Hi. I think "grouping into a dict of lists instead of grouping with `groupby(sorted(...))`" would be more enlightening than "but does not use itertools" to introduce your answer. (I agree that a dict of lists is better-suited than itertools.groupby for this problem, but there is nothing wrong with using itertools in general when it's useful)