Merge json objects present under duplicate keys
I have a json file like this:
{
    "parent1": {
        "child1": "bob"
    },
    "parent1": {
        "child2": "tom"
    },
    "parent2": {
        "child1": "jon"
    }
}

I want to merge the values present under duplicate toplevel keys. So the expected output should be:
{
    "parent1": {
        "child1": "bob",
        "child2": "tom"
    },
    "parent2": {
        "child1": "jon"
    }
}

Currently I am using the following code to check duplicate keys:
import json

def check_duplicates(pairs):
    d = {}
    for key, val in pairs:
        if key in d:
            raise ValueError(f"Duplicate key(s) found: {key}")
        else:
            d[key] = val
    return d

filename = "test.json"
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    try:
        data = json.load(f, object_pairs_hook=check_duplicates)
    except ValueError as err:
        print(f"{filename}: Failed to decode: {err}")

Any idea how I can merge them?

Are the values guaranteed to be json objects or may it happen they are arrays as well?

what if two children have the same name ?

@matszwecja No arrays should not be present.

@diggusbickus If it has same keys show an error that they cannot be merged

I'd fix whatever code is generating this: A JSON object is effectively a key/value store with the keys being strings. Having duplicate keys doesn't make sense in the first place. I'm not sure if this is formally valid though, so YMMV.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object.

As per valid JSON format, there should not be any duplicate key.
However, as we may have invalid JSON data, we sometimes need to clean it.
The following code raises an error for any invalid child.
import json


def merge_duplicates(data):
    clean_data = {}
    for parent, child_dict in data:
        if parent in clean_data:
            child_key = next(iter(child_dict))
            if child_key in clean_data[parent]:
                raise ValueError(f"Duplicate child(s) ({child_key}) found on key: {parent}")
            else:
                clean_data[parent].update(child_dict)
        else:
            clean_data[parent] = child_dict
    return clean_data


filename = "valid.json"
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f, object_pairs_hook=merge_duplicates)
print("valid.json", json.dumps(data, indent=4))

filename = "invalid.json"
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f, object_pairs_hook=merge_duplicates)
print("invalid.json", json.dumps(data, indent=4))

valid.json:
{
    "parent1": {
        "child1": "bob"
    },
    "parent1": {
        "child2": "tom"
    },
    "parent1": {
        "child3": "eve"
    },
    "parent2": {
        "child1": "jon"
    }
}

invalid.json:
{
    "parent1": {
        "child1": "bob"
    },
    "parent1": {
        "child2": "tom"
    },
    "parent1": {
        "child1": "foo"
    },
    "parent2": {
        "child1": "jon"
    }
}

Output:
valid.json {
    "parent1": {
        "child1": "bob",
        "child2": "tom",
        "child3": "eve"
    },
    "parent2": {
        "child1": "jon"
    }
}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/shovon/Codes/so/main.py", line 25, in <module>
    data = json.load(f, object_pairs_hook=merge_duplicates)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py", line 359, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/media/shovon/Codes/so/main.py", line 10, in merge_duplicates
    raise ValueError(f"Duplicate child(s) ({child_key}) found on key: {parent}")
ValueError: Duplicate child(s) (child1) found on key: parent1

Explanation:

Duplicate parent key handling: The merge_duplicates function uses the object_pairs_hook parameter to process each key-value pair in the JSON data as it is loaded. This ensures that the function can detect and handle duplicate parent keys.

Child key conflict detection: For each parent key, the function checks if the parent key already exists in the clean_data dictionary using next(iter(child_dict)). If it does, it checks if the new child key (within the duplicate parent key) already exists. If a duplicate child key is detected, a ValueError is raised, indicating the conflict. For example, repeating values for child1 for parent1 raises ValueError for invalid.json file.



You have the right idea with object_pairs_hook, but you still have to actually merge the values once you find a duplicate. Some examples of doing that are How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression in Python?
You didn't answer the requests for clarification on what to do if the child names are also duplicates, so I'll just arbitrarily pick a merge strategy of update, and use the latest. Alternatively, you could keep the first, or raise a KeyError.
import json
from io import StringIO

content = """{
    "parent1": {
        "child1": "bob"
    },
    "parent1": {
        "child2": "tom"
    },
    "parent2": {
        "child1": "jon"
    }
}
"""

def check_duplicates(pairs):
    d = {}
    for key, val in pairs:
        if key in d:
            d[key].update(val) # apply the merge here
        else:
            d[key] = val
    return d

with StringIO(content) as f:
    try:
        data = json.load(f, object_pairs_hook=check_duplicates)
        print(data)
    except ValueError as err:
        print(str(err))


{'parent1': {'child1': 'bob', 'child2': 'tom'}, 'parent2': {'child1': 'jon'}}

This does not handle arbitrary json. I am going with your assumptions about the structure of the json file, which I'll trust you to enforce.
